# Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to apply Cauchy-Lipshitz to say that the maximal solutions of  $$x''+\alpha x'+a x +\sin x =L$$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you.

Comment: If you meant [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem), it should be Lipschitz, no Lipshitz.

Answer (score 2):

We could start by writing it as a first order equation:

\begin{align}
u'&=-\alpha u -\alpha v-\sin(v)+L\\
v'&=u,
\end{align}
where $v:=x$ and $u:=x'$.

Now we have $y:=(u,v)$ and $y'=f(t,y(t))$ (in our case $y'=f(y)$). Show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. Observe that $||f(y_1)-f(y_2)||<L||y_1-y_2||$, where $L$ is the norm of the bounded linear function $$\left(\begin{matrix}-\alpha&-\alpha-1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right).$$

Compute $M$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Application of the theorem will give you existence and uniqueness in an interval $(t_0-a,t_0+a)$ where $a$ can be bounded. To get existence in $\mathbb{R}$ you can play with the bound ([see the bound here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Detailed_proof)) as you move $t_0$ to show that you can cover $\mathbb{R}$ with these intervals $[t_0-a,t_0+a]$.